# Plot multiple string value on bar plot side by side in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data set like

```
import pandas as pd

compnaies = ['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Google']
products = ['OS', 'Search', 'E-comm', 'E-comm', 'Social Media', 'OS']
average = [1.2,3.4,2.4,5.2,3.2,4.4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'company' : compnaies, 'product':products,
                    'average' : average})
df

   average  company     product
0   1.2    Microsoft    OS
1   3.4    Google       Search
2   2.4    Amazon       Search
3   5.2    Microsoft    Search
4   4.4    Google       OS
```

Now I want to plot in Python/MatPlotLib it like 
[image]

I am from R background and whatever I found here is converting the x axis in numeric index, then plot 2 numeric values and then name the group in hard coded way, Is there any standard way where I can plot the required graph.

Most of the places, I find the help like this code where we plot all numeric value with static group 
https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Just had a similar question - [see second version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516001/8881141)

Comment: thanks, it works for me so I am closing this ticket

Answer (score 0):

Closing this thread as this solution works for me

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

    #create toy dataframe
    np.random.seed(1234)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"clm1": ["X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"], "clm2": np.random.randint(1, 100, 6), "clm3": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]})

    #rearrange dataframe and plot
    df.pivot(index = "clm3", columns = "clm1", values = "clm2").plot.bar(edgecolor = "white")
    plt.xticks(rotation = 0)
    plt.show()
```

taken from : [python plot grouped bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502360/python-plot-grouped-bar-graph)